# how to change css to show two products in mobile mode for sv product tab of 7up-theme plugin?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

how to change css to show two products in mobile mode for sv product tab of 7up-theme plugin ?

i tried this css :

```css
@media(max-width:960px){
 .tab-content {
  width:50%;
  float:left; 
  }
  }
```

but By  the css code, the product takes only half the page and next product is not shown in the same column Next to previous product.

Comment: please add html code as well..

Comment: my site name is almahdionline.ir . you can take help of firebog to have html codes.Please watch the main page of website in mobile mode.

Comment: share the screenshot of issue section..

Comment: sorry . i am a newbie and i am not allowed to embed a photo in my posts . but my issue section is the first box of products that you see in mobile mode that show only one perfume and its Specifications below.